# How to choose a file path for fopen for php?

Tags: php, fopen

I'm a beginner at php and was trying to have a simple program that reads a file and echos the content. The txt file is in the same folder as the php file. I've been trying multiple file paths such as

- C:\Users\Data\Documents\project\read.txt
- read.txt
- project\read.txt

but none of these work. Thanks!

Comment: please include code in your question this said you can try `__DIR__ . "/[your-file-name]";`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `__DIR__` constant which returns the path to the PHP file in which it is used. Therefore

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__ . '/read.txt');
```

You can then use it independently on the path to the script as long as the txt file is in the same folder as the PHP file.